# While loop keeps printing constantly, doesn't allow for user input

Tags: python, input, while-loop, break

I'm trying to complete this assignment asking user for a number and if it's not -1 then it should loop. if it's -1 then to calculate the average of the other numbers.
I'm getting stuck with the actual loop - it endlessly keeps printing the message to user to enter a different number - as in the picture - and doesn't give user a chance to enter a different number. Please help, I've been through so many videos and blogs and can't figure out what's actually wrong.

```
#creating a list for later calculations:
wrong = []

#asking for input:
input("Hi, We're gonna play a guessing game. When asked enter a number between -10 and 10.\nIf not correct you'll have to guess again ^-^")
num =int(input("number:"))

#looping
while num != -abs(1):
  wrong.append(num)
  print("Nope, guess again:")
  if num == -abs(1):
    break
    av = sum(wrong) / len(wrong)
    print ("You got it! The average of your wrong answers is: ")
    print(av)
    print("The End")
print("Nope, guess again:")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: You are not changing `num` to get out of the loop. So if the input is 5 num will be equal to 5 forever.

Comment: Put the `num = int(input("number"))` *inside* the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the `input` function in the loop if you want it to work. I corrected the rest of your code as well, you don't need the if condition. More generally you should avoid to use `break`, it often means you are doing something wrong with your loop condition. Here it is redondant and the code after `break` is never executed.

```py
wrong = []

input("Hi, We're gonna play a guessing game. When asked enter a number between -10 and 10.\nIf not correct you'll have to guess again ^-^")
num = int(input("Number: "))

while num != -1 :
  wrong.append(num)
  num = int(input("Nope, guess again: "))

av = sum(wrong) / len(wrong)
print(f"You got it! The average of your wrong answers is: {av}\nThe End")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just breaking the loop before printing the results, first print the results, then break the loop.

And a while loop isn't necessary for your program, use if condition wrapped in a function instead:

```
#creating a list for later calculations:
wrong = []

#asking for input:
input("Hi, We're gonna play a guessing game. When asked enter a number between -10 and 10.\nIf not correct you'll have to guess again ^-^")


#looping
def go():
    num =int(input("number:"))
    if num != -abs(1):
      wrong.append(num)
      print("Nope, guess again:")
      if num == -abs(1):
        av = sum(wrong) / len(wrong)
        print ("You got it! The average of your wrong answers is: ")
        print(av)
        print("The End")
        break
    print("Nope, guess again:")
    go()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issues in the code.
If you want to get inputs in while looping, you should include getting input code inside the while loop like below,

```
while num != -1:
 ......
 num =int(input("number:"))
 ......
```

Also you don't have to include 'break' inside the while loop because, when num != 1, the loop will stop.

Answer (score 0):

You should ask for input inside your loop, but you just print "Nope, guess again:".

```
wrong = []

print("Hi, We're gonna play a guessing game. When asked enter a number between -10 and 10.\n"
      "If not correct you'll have to guess again ^-^")

num = int(input("number: "))

# looping
while num != -1:
    wrong.append(num)
    num = int(input("Nope, guess again: "))

av = sum(wrong) / len(wrong)
print(f"You got it! The average of your wrong answers is: {av}\nThe End")
```